# Data chopping issue in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-manipulation

Problem 1 : I have different ID's for each ID I want to chop the `Item vs. Value` curve at the minimum `Value`. Basically, I want to filter out the values and keep only until it goes minimum value.

Problem 2. Can I extrapolate by fitting the chopped curve in Python?

Please help me with faster solution because I have large dataset, `numpy` solution would be good.

```
ID        Item  Value
30702556    40  1
30702556    41  1
30702556    42  1
30702556    43  1
30702556    44  1.000408
30702556    45  1.006702067
30702556    46  1
30702556    47  1
30702556    48  1
30702556    49  1.000157628
30702556    50  1.001172713
30702556    51  1.009517935
30702556    52  1
30702556    53  1.000502562
30702556    54  1.001030023
30702556    55  1
30702556    56  1.000444755
30702556    57  1.000199956
30702556    58  1
30702556    59  1
30702556    60  1.00032533
30702556    61  0.996561721
30702556    62  0.994058276
30702556    63  0.994029863
30702556    64  0.995741839
30702556    65  0.996079035
30702556    66  0.992283214
30702556    67  0.992360022
30702556    68  0.991403573
30702556    69  0.989097475
30702556    70  0.989217641
30702556    71  0.988622481
30702556    72  0.987000163
30702556    73  0.984607074
30702556    74  0.983260544
30702556    75  0.983233331
30702556    76  0.976835524
30702556    77  0.976070994
30702556    78  0.975937075
30702556    79  0.968117537
30702556    80  0.967753864
30702556    81  0.963275228
30702556    82  0.960392687
30702556    83  0.953357783
30702556    84  0.941583499
30702556    85  0.937935151
30702556    86  0.92811891
30702556    87  0.924914786
30702556    88  0.912813207
30702556    89  0.892052451
30702556    90  0.875778411
30702556    91  0.876931504
30702556    92  0.847877617
30702556    93  0.834768706
30702556    94  0.841510584
30702556    95  0.798555032
30702556    96  0.781663978
30702556    97  0.731056793
30702556    98  0.71332851
30702556    99  0.808900212
30702556    100 0.822300396
30702556    101 0.920676291
30702556    102 0.911704187
30702556    103 1
30702556    104 1
30702556    105 1
30702556    106 1
30702556    107 1
30702556    108 1
30702556    109 1
30702556    110 1
30702556    111 1
30702556    112 1
30702556    113 1
30702556    114 1
30702556    115 1
30702556    116 1
30702556    117 1
30702556    118 1
30702556    119 1
30703716    40  1
30703716    41  1
30703716    42  1
30703716    43  1
30703716    44  1.000408
30703716    45  1.006702067
30703716    46  1
30703716    47  1
30703716    48  1
30703716    49  1.000157628
30703716    50  1.001172713
30703716    51  1.009517935
30703716    52  1
30703716    53  1.000502562
30703716    54  1.001030023
30703716    55  1
30703716    56  1.000444755
30703716    57  1.000199956
30703716    58  1
30703716    59  1
30703716    60  1.00032533
30703716    61  0.996561721
30703716    62  0.994058276
30703716    63  0.994029863
30703716    64  0.995741839
30703716    65  0.996079035
30703716    66  0.992283214
30703716    67  0.992360022
30703716    68  0.991403573
30703716    69  0.989097475
30703716    70  0.989217641
30703716    71  0.988622481
30703716    72  0.987000163
30703716    73  0.984607074
30703716    74  0.983260544
30703716    75  0.983233331
30703716    76  0.976835524
30703716    77  0.976070994
30703716    78  0.975937075
30703716    79  0.968117537
30703716    80  0.967753864
30703716    81  0.963275228
30703716    82  0.960392687
30703716    83  0.953357783
30703716    84  0.941583499
30703716    85  0.937935151
30703716    86  0.92811891
30703716    87  0.924914786
30703716    88  0.912813207
30703716    89  0.892052451
30703716    90  0.875778411
30703716    91  0.876931504
30703716    92  0.847877617
30703716    93  0.834768706
30703716    94  0.841510584
30703716    95  0.798555032
30703716    96  0.781663978
30703716    97  0.731056793
30703716    98  0.71332851
30703716    99  0.808900212
30703716    100 0.822300396
30703716    101 0.920676291
30703716    102 0.911704187
30703716    103 1
30703716    104 1
30703716    105 1
30703716    106 1
30703716    107 1
30703716    108 1
30703716    109 1
30703716    110 1
30703716    111 1
30703716    112 1
30703716    113 1
30703716    114 1
30703716    115 1
30703716    116 1
30703716    117 1
30703716    118 1
30703716    119 1
```

Comment: So, what's the expected output for the given sample?

Comment: Expected output should chop data after the row 30702556    98  0.71332851, this has to be done for all IDs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `.loc[:df.Value.idxmin()]`

```
df.groupby('ID', group_keys=False).apply(lambda df: df.loc[:df.Value.idxmin()])
```

---

```
           ID  Item     Value
0    30702556    40  1.000000
1    30702556    41  1.000000
2    30702556    42  1.000000
3    30702556    43  1.000000
4    30702556    44  1.000408
5    30702556    45  1.006702
6    30702556    46  1.000000
7    30702556    47  1.000000
8    30702556    48  1.000000
9    30702556    49  1.000158
10   30702556    50  1.001173
11   30702556    51  1.009518
12   30702556    52  1.000000
13   30702556    53  1.000503
14   30702556    54  1.001030
15   30702556    55  1.000000
16   30702556    56  1.000445
17   30702556    57  1.000200
18   30702556    58  1.000000
19   30702556    59  1.000000
20   30702556    60  1.000325
21   30702556    61  0.996562
22   30702556    62  0.994058
23   30702556    63  0.994030
24   30702556    64  0.995742
25   30702556    65  0.996079
26   30702556    66  0.992283
27   30702556    67  0.992360
28   30702556    68  0.991404
29   30702556    69  0.989097
..        ...   ...       ...
109  30703716    69  0.989097
110  30703716    70  0.989218
111  30703716    71  0.988622
112  30703716    72  0.987000
113  30703716    73  0.984607
114  30703716    74  0.983261
115  30703716    75  0.983233
116  30703716    76  0.976836
117  30703716    77  0.976071
118  30703716    78  0.975937
119  30703716    79  0.968118
120  30703716    80  0.967754
121  30703716    81  0.963275
122  30703716    82  0.960393
123  30703716    83  0.953358
124  30703716    84  0.941583
125  30703716    85  0.937935
126  30703716    86  0.928119
127  30703716    87  0.924915
128  30703716    88  0.912813
129  30703716    89  0.892052
130  30703716    90  0.875778
131  30703716    91  0.876932
132  30703716    92  0.847878
133  30703716    93  0.834769
134  30703716    94  0.841511
135  30703716    95  0.798555
136  30703716    96  0.781664
137  30703716    97  0.731057
138  30703716    98  0.713329
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC:

```
df.loc[df.groupby('ID')['Value'].idxmin()]
```

Comment: It just gives the minimum value records

Comment: Ah.. I see. piRSquared as the best answer.